# The Router Mac Address

Tags: router, mac-address

Some sites  can get the mac address of my network interface bu using cookies or java script ! 
but can they get my **router** mac address ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "a site"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  site who blocks sockpuppet

Comment: @MRTgang We only know what you tell us. Your question asks for a way "to do that", but doesn't even explain what "that" is. If you're having trouble with a particular web site or service of some kind, why not talk to the support staff or administration for that service, rather than asking other people to guess what some unspecified site or service might or might not do.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Can a site get my router mac address?

A: No.

Comment: +1 But can you back it up with a wikipedia link!?